# What is this - No MediaQuery widget ancestor found. Scaffold widgets require MediaQuery ancestor

Tags: flutter

Using Flutter ver 3.3.6 trying to creating a simple food menu.
Here's what I got so far

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {runApp(const FoodList());}

class FoodList extends StatelessWidget {
  const FoodList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Food List"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: const <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Food Item 1"),
            trailing: Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Food Item 2"),
            trailing: Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Food Item 3"),
            trailing: Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Food Item 4"),
            trailing: Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Food Item 5"),
            trailing: Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: Text('Submit'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Scaffold` needs a `MaterialApp` (or equivalent) ancestor. Create another project using the counter example and compare. Or look at the `Counter` example in dartpad.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `materialApp`, your code should be look like this:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {runApp(const MyApp());}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FoodList(),
    );
  }
}

class FoodList extends StatelessWidget {
  const FoodList({super.key});
```

Comment: Using the above code added the materialApp (Flutter Ver 3.3.6 on Android Studio) got this message - The following assertion was thrown building Scaffold(dirty, state: ScaffoldState#4f1cf(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)):
No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.

Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a MediaQuery ancestor was: Scaffold
  dirty
  state: ScaffoldState#4f1cf(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)
The ownership chain for the affected widget is: "Scaffold ← FoodList ← [root]"

Comment: i run the code exactly how its written but i dont see that error. it might be somewhere else affecting your code. Since i cant see how you implemented my code, i can't say something any further. To make sure your setup is correct,  delete your main.dart file and run `flutter create .`,

Comment: Thanks John it works now once I started all over again. Did a comparison between the new flutter file and the edited flutter file they look exactly the same. I seen this happen a few times before everything is identical between the edited one and a new one. But the new one will work correctly. Why does that happen sometimes?

Comment: there are a lot of factors affecting it especially when installing third-party plugins. that's why we have the command `flutter clean`